# Diagnosing Response Times

Tags: angularjs, laravel, optimization, developer-tools

I don't have too much experience in diagnosing the source of longer response times, so I was curious to find out about some methods from the more experienced.

I have a simple index page of paginated records, and each time I click to load a new page, it says the response time is a little over 300ms for 25 records. The query to pull the records isn't anything complicated, and maybe 300ms isn't that long. But I'd still like to know how to find what's taking a majority of that time, because it just feels like it's taking a bit of time.

What tools or methods could I use to find out any bottlenecks? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at xhprof.

Comment: debugbar, also is the database on the same server i had a really long wait on a simple query only to figure out that the response is super slow when you are not running a db server on the same machine.

Comment: Chrome developer tools > Network tab ... it's going to show all HTTP requests including response time.  Once you figure out exactly which request is the bottleneck, you can start looking at the server side code for why it is taking so long.   Beyond that you can get into more advanced performance analysis on the client side with the Timeline and Performance tabs or the Batarang extension.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'll check those out. Yeah, the DB is on the same server as Apache.

Answer (score 1):

DebugBar is a great way to get more visibility into your Laravel App's execution. It will break out all the SQL queries and provide timings.

In addition to DebugBar, adding a simple Benchmarking class is another tactic I often use. To do this, start a timer at the very beginning of your app. Here is a sample class I've used in the past (made a couple tweaks and didn't test the code below):

```
<?php

class Benchmark
{
    public static $events = [];

    public static function start()
    {
        static::$events = [];
        static::bench('start');
    }

    public static function end()
    {
        static::bench('end');
    }

    public static function bench($event)
    {
        static::$events[$event] = static::time();
    }

    public static function time()
    {
        list($msec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
        return ($msec+$sec) - static::$events['start'];
    }

    public static function report()
    {
        print_r(static::$events);
    }
}
```

Implementation would be:

```
Benchmark::start();
Benchmark::bench('finished big query');
Benchmark::end();
```

then print out the benchmark somewhere at the end of execution:

```
<?php Benchmark::report() ?>
```

**Check MySQL**

Most of the time the slowdown is the database.

If you find a particular query that is slowing the page load down, use the MySQL [slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html) to isolate problems further and the MySQL `explain` command to dissect the query to make improvements.

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation. I'll definitely check those out.